# Android OS Storage Usage

Tags: internal-storage, storage

I have two fresh Galaxy device on Android 9 , the difference is in storage , one is 512GB and another is 128GB. System usage in both is different , 128GB version uses 27GB on fresh but the 512GB version use up to 47GB. There is no installed app and both devices are just out of box.

My question is why Android uses more storage on 512GB version and how can I decrease the amount? If it's dynamic what's the reason and should it decrease if the device is out of storage?

---

I don't want to root both devices, so I checked it on another device which is previously rooted. By `df -h` I see it's about device partition, the rooted device is 32GB out of which only 25GB is available. Other partitions are listed as below:

[image]

As you can see there is some duplicate mounted partitions , but sum of their sizes will be 32GB.

Comment: Root both and take a comparison of `du -h /data | sort -h`.

Comment: Check the partition size using an app like [DiskInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo). On Android the system has on own partition. If the partition is larger the free size for user data is smaller.

Comment: @Robert `df -h` would also do the job. Just because eMMC is larger, could `/system` be larger on the same model? Shouldn't only `userdata` differ, that's what custom paid extra for.

Comment: Would you consider sharing your results? I just asked a very similar question here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244678/installed-base-system-size-on-galaxy-s10-smartphone Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With root take a comparison of space usage on both devices by executing `du -h /data | sort -h`. Without root you can rely on figures reported by filesystem by running `df -h`.

From the updated screenshot you have attached, no partition is duplicate mounted. If you are talking about `tmpfs`, it's a volatile filesystem which lives in RAM and is vanished on reboot. It isn't part of your persistent storage.

Your `/data` and `/system` added make 29GiB. That's what you get on a 32GB device. Up to 2GiB difference comes because of Gigabyte (GB) and Gibibyte (GiB). Also there are usually 50+ [partitions on an Android device](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565) which aren't mounted (except a few filesystems). And there's free space left by manufacturers for over-provisioning of flash memory.

For details see: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)