# Installed base system size on Galaxy S10+ smartphone

Tags: internal-storage, device-firmware

I recently had a brief chance to look at a Samsung Galaxy S10+ smartphone with 512GB of internal storage and 8GB RAM. After the base setup, there was already about 70GB of used memory on the device, which made me curious.

In the system settings the device claimed that the "Base System" already consumes a whooping 47GB (!!!) of storage in this device. I can't believe this is real. The previous device (Galaxy S7) only had 32GB of internal memory and the system was just ~5GB, and that included the mirrored partition Android keeps around for seamless updates. Within a few weeks of usage the used space on this device is already about 80GB, and that's without having gigabytes of photos or videos around.

**My Question**: How can I find out what is actually included in this gigantic "base system"? I found some SM-G975 base images on the net (e.g. samfirms.com) but those are all much smaller (~6..7GB unzipped).
Preferably without having to root or otherwise modify the device (which I don't own).

**Update**: Found related question here: [Android OS Storage Usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214390/android-os-storage-usage) So it's reproducable. I wonder what the author of that question found out?

Comment: Check the partition list as shown in the linked question. Then you know more details. I would assume that the cache and other partitions are increased. You also have to consider that all those Samsung pre-installed app got an update which is then installed in data partition.

Comment: might be related (btw you can't root without data loss therefore you are limited to shell permissions) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220729